# directory with slash or backslash in pycharm vs google colab

Tags: python, pycharm, google-colaboratory, backslash, slash

I have a basic question about using slash or backslash.

here is my code:

```
import os

path1 = r'c:\super'
path2 = r'c:/super'

print(os.path.basename(path1))
print(os.path.basename(path2))
```

the result from pycharm is:

```
super
super
```

the result from google colab is:

```
c:\super
super
```

why do they perform so differently on both platforms?

Comment: same version of python? what's colab's operating system? what pycharm's?

Comment: pycharm 2020.2 commuity, with python 3.6.1, and colab with chrome on window with python 3.6.9. isn't that matter?

Comment: colab isn't running in your browser, it's running on a server. what kind of server? look at `sys.platform`

Comment: ic, it shows me this is linux, not my platform I am running window, so the window and linux behave differently, and is that the reason why to my question?

Comment: yes. drives are not denoted as e.g., `C:\` in linux

Comment: thank, you answer it. maybe I ask you little more, when using os.listdir(),  window can show all folder, sub-folders and files, but google colab only show everything main folder, and won't go deeper to item from sub-folders. Isn't it because again the difference between the window and Linux platform?

Answer (score 0):

I believe is an issue of 'GCC implementation' of the python compiler.

I've tried this:

```
import os
import sys

path=[]
path.append('c:\super')
path.append('c:\a\b\super')
path.append(r'c:\super')
path.append(r'c:\a\b\super')
path.append('c:\\a\\b\\super')
path.append('c:/a/super')
path.append(r'c:/a/super')

for p in path:
  print (os.path.basename(p))

print(sys.version)
```

Colaboratory reports

```
c:\super
c:\super
c:\super
c:\a\b\super
c:\a\b\super
super
super
3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0]
```

The same code on repl-it (for instance) get:

[answer from repl.it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfDN4.png)

But the same code in 3.8.5 / Intel gets
[answer from local Intel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqhfh.png)

Comment: if regardless of python version, you said 'Intel gets' means you are using window to test the same thing?,and you compare with result in colab? so your result and mine result are the same. And I still dont get it why backslash on window python can show basename, but in colab can't?

Comment: Both colab and repl.it run over GCC - Gnu C Compiler - both are (probably) running in Unix-like operating systems. And in Unix-based systems the path separator is / (normal slash) - backward slash \ is treated as a 'normal' char, and so the basename includes the \ (backslash) .